# How to fix this Two keys pressed conflict?

Tags: c#, forms, class, events, event-handling

I have a problem that I'm struggling with.. I want to move an image using my keyboard to the left, right, up or down and in a diagonal way. I searched the web and found, that to use 2 diffrent keys I need to remember the previous key, so for that I'm using a bool dictionary.

in my main Form class this is how the KeyDown event looks like:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    baseCar.carAccelerate(e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower());
    carBox.Refresh(); //carbox is a picturebox in my form that store the image I want to move.
}
```

My KeyUp event:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    baseCar.carBreak(e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower());
}
```

My Paint event:

```
private void carBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Car, baseCar.CharPosX, baseCar.CharPosY); // Car is just an image
}
```

And my baseCar class:

```
private Dictionary KeysD = new Dictionary(); // there is a method to set the W|A|S|D Keys, like: KeysD.Add("w",false)

public void carAccelerate(string moveDir)
{       
    KeysD[moveDir] = true;
    moveBeta();
}
public void moveBeta()
{
    if (KeysD["w"])
    {
        this.CharPosY -= this.carMoveYSpeed;
    }
    if (KeysD["s"])
    {
        CharPosY += carMoveYSpeed;
    }
    if (KeysD["a"])
    {
        CharPosX -= carMoveXSpeed;
    }
    if (KeysD["d"])
    {
        CharPosX += carMoveXSpeed;
    }
}
public void carBreak(string str)
{
    KeysD[str] = false;
}
```

Anyway it works, but my problem is that I can't get back to the first pressed key for example:

I pressed W to move up and then the D key to go diagonal, how ever when I release the D key it wont go Up again because the KeyDown event is "dead" and wont call the carAccelerate() method again.. and I can't figure out how to fix it..

Can any one help me please? Maybe there is a better way to handle the keys? im open to any ideas! And I hope you can understand it, my english isnt the best :S

Comment: Any (good) reason you are trying to do this with WinForms? XNA would make your life a lot easier wouldn't it?

Comment: When you release the W key after releasing the D key, does the KeyUp event fire again?  Also, KeyDown and KeyUp are instant events, it looks like you need something to recognize "For as long as this key is held down" or similar

Comment: how about a continuing loop that updates the position and draws, and just have what ever key is press at the time of the update the keys is registred and then move the car. loop needs to be quite fast though

Comment: KingCronus - yes it will but I is for a school project and i must do it on forms.. :\ 

Nevyn - yes, and the recognize is my problem, cant think about anything..

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't hande the key events directly for these kinds of things. Instead, you keep track of what keys are currently pressed. Physics calculations are done on some interval, which can be done with a timer. Quick and dirty example below. However, this is not the kind of thing you should be attempting with WinForms.

```
    private const int ACCELERATION = 1;

    private HashSet<Keys> pressed;
    private int velocityX = 0;
    private int velocityY = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pressed = new HashSet<Keys>();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        pressed.Add(e.KeyCode);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        pressed.Remove(e.KeyCode);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        car.Location = new Point(
            car.Left + velocityX,
            car.Top + velocityY);
        if (pressed.Contains(Keys.W)) velocityY -= ACCELERATION;
        if (pressed.Contains(Keys.A)) velocityX -= ACCELERATION;
        if (pressed.Contains(Keys.S)) velocityY += ACCELERATION;
        if (pressed.Contains(Keys.D)) velocityX += ACCELERATION;
    }
```